# Send variable from post request to a simple middleware with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a this app.post :

```
        app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res,next) => {
        let file = req.file.path;
        let var1= path.basename(file,path.extname(file));
                   req.var1=var1;
                     console.log("le nom du fichier est : " + req.var1);
                        next();
                      })
```

Now i want to send this var1 to this middleware function because i am working with react and i want to dispatch it with ComponentDidMount  but i get always undefined :

```
                  function last(req,res,next){
              console.log(req.var1);

              let results={

                        first:req.var1,

                      others:'req.var2'
                    }
              res.send(results);

          }
          app.post('/Convert',last);
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Where in the request chain is the `last` middleware attached? Presumably *after* the `post`? FWIW I would say [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) would be a better fit here.

Comment: where i shall use res.locals ? I put it in the app.post but no way it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: I'm suggesting you replace `req.var1 = var1` with `res.locals.var1 = var1` and then when fetching back out the result you can use `first: res.locals.var1`. By all accounts it shouldn't matter, adding properties to the request object should do the same thing, it's just `res.locals` is a mechanism already in place for this type of thing (moreso if you want to render data into a view). If neither works then it sounds like your middleware setup is wrong, you'd need to show more code.

Comment: Thank u James , i appreciate your help . It doesn't work but maybe i find another solution thnxx a lot

Comment: The point I am making is both of these approaches *should* work, the fact they aren't suggests to me it's a problem with how you've setup your middleware - if you show this code then perhaps I could help further